# Prolog predicate with multiple lists

Tags: prolog

I'm using `swipl` but working the adventure tuorial from [Amzi!](https://amzi.com/AdventureInProlog/a1start.php).  The syntax difference is causing me a headache.  After setting up the facts, I have these statements

```
list_things(Place) :-
    location(X, Place),
    tab(2),
    write(X), nl,
    false.
   

list_connections(Place) :-
    connect(Place, X),
    tab(2),
    write(X), nl,
    false.

look :-
    here(Place),
    write('You are in the '), write(Place), nl,
    write("You can go to: "), nl,
    list_connections(Place), nl,
    write('You can see: '), nl,
    list_things(Place).
```

When I run `look.`, it only outputs the first list from `list_connections`.  That is

```
?- look.
You are in the kitchen
You can go to:
  office
  cellar
  dining room
false.
```

Now, I understand the `false` at the end of the function is terminating the `look`, but I don't know the correct syntax in `swipl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, I understand the false at the end of the function is terminating the look

The false at the end of `list_connections(Place)` forces it to backtrack and retry, writing all the connected places as it does so. Once it has got through them all and failed for the last time, I think there is supposed to be another rule for it:

```
list_connections(_).
```

I see it here in Amzi! chapter 5:

[image: Screenshot of Amzi chapter 5 page]

That rule is a "succeed for anything" rule which will allow `look` to carry on and then list_things can run. And there is a similar one for list_things.

Comment: Your explanation and this example have really shown me how differently I need to think from functional programming.  Thank you!